# The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). It is not because of operator "or"

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror, rolling-computation

vol_df value is as follows:

```
    stock transactions
0   6668624093
1   7000414730
2   7666161224
3   5882916889
4   6301315220
5   4240619512
6   5152771960
7   5604573262
8   5632000282
9   4141531366
10  5099018549
11  5269035601
12  5587861806
13  4516673303
14  4591419535
15  3914740328
16  4347751931
17  4745714862
18  4911766203
19  4901183056
```

but why i do `avg_vol_df=pd.Series(vol_df).rolling(window=20).mean()`
I get:

`"The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."`

please help me. Thank you very much.

I tried `avg_vol_df=vol_df.rolling(20).mean()`

I get `NaN` for answers

I tried `avg_vol_df=vol_df.rolling(min_periods=1).mean()`

I get scientifical notation like `6.66~~~~+09`

Comment: can you please format the question properly? and also state, what exactly is it that you want to achieve instead of only sharing the code?

Comment: Please format the code - select it and type `ctrl-k`.
.. [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Aways show the complete Traceback - format it as code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `pd.Series` on a DataFrame. If you have a dataframe with one column, you can use `pd.DataFrame.squeeze()` to change it to a series, but I would recommend just selecting the column you want:

```
vol_df["stock transactions"].rolling(window=20).mean()
```

or omitting it altogether to have the rolling be applied to all columns:

```
vol_df.rolling(window=20).mean()
```

---

The NaN values occur because a rolling window with size 20 needs at least 20 values, so your input contains only 1 such window.

The scientific notation happens because computing the mean returns a floating point value, and your inputs are large enough to be formatted in scientific notation. You can customize this behavior if you'd like.